# Deducting Numbers From Database Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table venue which consists of:
idVenue
name
description
room_size

What i'm trying to do is

ie. Venue A can have 5 person.
In DB, i have a room_size field which is 5.

So everytime a person is being selected to Venue A, just deduct 1 from the total (which is 5 for now). Once it reaches 0, then don't show out the Venue.

I heard flagging is possible, how do i actually go upon doing that?

Here's the code:

do_select.php

```
  <?php

session_start();

if(($_SESSION['role'])!='Admin'){
 echo "You have not logged in as admin yet.<br/>";
 echo "Please <a href='login.php'>login</a>.";
 exit;
}
?>

<?php

 //member id
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $idimplode = implode (", ", $id);
    $idexplode=  explode(", ", $idimplode);

 //accept, reject
 $select=$_POST['select'];
 $comma = implode (", ", $select);
 $comma1 = explode(", ", $comma);

 $check =($idexplode);

 //class id
 $idc = $_POST['idc'];



 include('dbconfig.php');

  for($i=0;$i< sizeof($comma1);$i++)
  {
   if($comma1[$i]=="accept")
   {


      //Select Query if status is accept

      $query="UPDATE attendance SET status='accept' WHERE Member_idMember ='$check[$i]' and Class_idClass='$idc'" ;
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));  



   } 

   else
   {
      //Select Query if status is reject
      $query2="UPDATE attendance SET status='reject' WHERE Member_idMember ='$check[$i]' and Class_idClass='$idc'" ;
      $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));

   }

  }



     //select members based on status

     $query3 = "SELECT * FROM member m, attendance a, class c
        WHERE a.Member_idMember = m.idMember
        AND a.Class_idClass = c.idClass
        AND a.status = 'accept'
        AND a.Class_idClass = '$idc'
        ";
     $result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die (mysqli_connect_error($link));


     //select query to get the class dates
     $query4 = "SELECT day01, day02, day03, day04, day05, day06, day07, day08, day09, day10, day11, day12 FROM class 
     WHERE idClass = '$idc'";

     $result4 = mysqli_query($link, $query4) or die (mysqli_connect_error($link));



     //select query to get venue id
     $query6 = "SELECT DISTINCT idVenue FROM venue";
     $result6 = mysqli_query($link, $query6) or die (mysqli_connect_error($link));


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_NUM))
       {
        $day[] = implode(", ", $row);
       }
        $iday = implode(", ", $day);
        $eday = explode(", ", $iday);



 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result6, MYSQL_NUM))
       {
        $ven[] = implode(",", $row);
       }
        $iven = implode(", ", $ven);
        $even = explode(", ", $iven);


 $date = ($eday);
 $venue= ($even);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>ST JOHN</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>

   <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
   <div id="wrapper">

         <!-- Begin Header -->
         <div id="header">

         <img src="Image/1.jpg" width="900" height="100" /> 

   </div>
   <!-- End Header -->

   <!-- Begin Navigation -->
         <div id="navigation">
  <a href="index.php"><img src="Image/4.png" width="30" height="30" ></a> Welcome!!! <br>;
  <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>;

   </div>
   <!-- End Navigation -->

         <!-- Begin Faux Columns -->
   <div id="faux">

         <!-- Begin Left Column -->
         <div id="leftcolumn">
   <center><img src="Image/2.jpg" width="150" height="100" /><br>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#home">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">Public Courses</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Cadet Affairs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">Events</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul></center>


         </div>
         <!-- End Left Column -->

         <!-- Begin Right Column -->
         <div id="rightcolumn">


      <h1>Assign Venue</h1><br/>

        <?php 

   echo"<table border='1'>";
   echo"<th>Name</th>";
   echo"<th>Signup Datetime</th>";
   echo"<th>Status</th>";
   echo"<th>Class</th>";
   echo"<th>Venue</th>";


 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3))
 {
   $idc=$row['idClass'];
   $id=$row['idMember'];
   $Name = $row['name'];
   $Status = $row['status'];
   $Signup_datetime = $row['signup_datetime'];
   $class=$row['Class_idClass'];
   $idt=$row['Time_Slot_idTime_Slot'];


   echo "<form method='post' action='assign_venue.php'>"; 



   echo "<tr>";

   echo "<td>".$Name."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$Signup_datetime."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$Status."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$class."</td>";


    echo "<input name='idc' type='hidden' value= '$idc'/>";
   echo "<input name='id[]' type='hidden' value= '$id'/>";

   echo "<td><select id ='idv[]' name='idv[]'>";

   for ($v=0; $v <count($venue); $v++)
   { 
    for ($d=0; $d <count($date); $d++)
    {

     //select query to determine which are the dates that are in conflict with each other
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM  venue v, class c, attendance a
     WHERE a.Venue_idVenue = v.idVenue
     AND a.Class_idClass = c.idClass
     AND v.idVenue = '$venue[$v]'
     AND (day01='$date[$d]' OR day02='$date[$d]' OR day03='$date[$d]' OR day04='$date[$d]' OR day05='$date[$d]' OR day06='$date[$d]' 
     OR day07='$date[$d]' OR day08='$date[$d]' OR day09='$date[$d]' OR day10='$date[$d]' OR day11='$date[$d]' OR day12='$date[$d]')
     AND c.Time_Slot_idTime_Slot = '$idt'"; 

     $rs = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_connect_error($link));

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
     {
      //if there are no conflict, then display the venue
      if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) != 0)
      {
       $ve[]= $row['idVenue'];
       break;
      }
     } 

    }
   }


   $if = implode(",", $ve);
   $ef = explode(",", $if);
   $ve = ($ef);

   for ($f=0; $f <count($ve); $f++)
   {
    //select query to get venue id and name
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM venue WHERE idVenue != '$ve[$f]'";
    $rs1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1) or die (mysqli_connect_error($link));
   }


   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs1))
   { 
    //display venue id and venue name
    $idv=$row['idVenue'];
    $name=$row['name'];

    echo"<option name='idv[]' value='$idv'>$name</option> ";
   }


   echo "</select>"; 

 }


 echo "</table>";
 echo "<td><input type='submit' value= 'Submit'> 
 </form>";

mysqli_close($link);

?>

      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- End Right Column -->

      <div class="clear"></div>

         </div>    
         <!-- End Faux Columns --> 

         <!-- Begin Footer -->
         <div id="footer">

               <center><p>Copyright© St. John Ambulance Singapore @ 420, Beach Road, Singapore 199582 Tel: 6298 0300 Fax: 6296 5797<a href="http://www.sjas.org.sg/association/Images/Map.JPG">click here for map</a></p></center> 

         </div>
   <!-- End Footer -->

   </div>
   <!-- End Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say that you use implode and explode to filter strings. What are you filtering them for?

Answer (score 0):

you should have another field called current_occupancy

When you create the row

`update venue set current_occupancy = room_size where id = <idOfVenue>`

Then when someone selects:

`update venue set current_occupancy = current_occupancy - 1 where id = <idOfVenue>`

And only show fields that match

`select * from venue where current_occupancey > 0 <whatever else>`

Comment: I dont quite get it, cause im using some filtering statement like 'implode' to actually filter out available rooms so that user can choose them and assign them to the various courses. Do u mind i can upload my code here and u can take a look? i'm a bit confused.